# Fill the div box with grey around image and text on hover

Tags: css, html, hover

How would I add a fill of grey to the div box around the image and text if I hover over it with css?

http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/G3rLu/

```
    <div id="wrapper-icons">
    <div class="icons_row">
        <div class="icons_cell1">
            <a href="http://www.thesurfboardproject.com/" target="_blank"><img alt="Surfboard" height="140" src="http://www.thesurfboardproject.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/JoseAngelGreg-Noll-1010-640x360.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" width="160" /> </a>
            <p class="rtecenter"><a href="http://www.thesurfboardproject.com/" target="_blank">Surfboard 1</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="icons_cell2">
            <a href="http://www.apple.com/" target="_blank"><img alt="Surfboard" height="140" src="http://www.thesurfboardproject.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/1957-Hobie-Balsa.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" width="160" /> </a>
            <p class="rtecenter"><a href="http://www.apple.com/" target="_blank">Surfboard 2</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="icons_cell3">
            <a href="http://www.ibm.com/" target="_blank"><img alt="Surfboard" height="140" src="http://www.thesurfboardproject.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Interisland-Gun.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" width="160" /> </a>
            <p class="rtecenter"><a href="http://www.ibm.com/" target="_blank">Surfboard 3</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="icons_cell4">
            <a href="http://www.espn.com/" target="_blank"><img alt="Surfboard" height="140" src="http://previewcf.turbosquid.com/Preview/2010/12/03__01_46_00/Surfboard_V3_2.jpge90d89a5-aaf9-44ac-b8cc-3327a5dc064bLarger.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" width="160" /> </a>
            <p class="rtecenter"><a href="http://www.espn.com/" target="_blank">Surfboard 4</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `border: 2px solid transparent;` to `.icons_cell1, .icons_cell2, .icons_cell3, .icons_cell4` and then add:

```
.icons_cell1:hover, .icons_cell2:hover, .icons_cell3:hover, .icons_cell4:hover {
    border:2px solid #BBB;
}
```

If you apply just the hover to the code, you'll see that in a fiddle, the content moves when the border appears. To fix that, we can put the transparent border on the cells by default.

I also recommend what others have suggested, and give your divs two classes, so that you can make your CSS smaller.

Comment: I changed it a bit. I added a class .greyBoxOnHover:hover {
    background-color: #e2e3e4;
}

Comment: I'm still a little confused about what you mean. Perhaps you are looking to do a background: grey; instead of a border?

Comment: Yes, I did mean a background grey. Do you think it looks odd now? Not sure if I like the look of the background

Comment: @user3075987: I added some padding to the top of the images so that the background isn't right at the image edge. Look at the syntaxes used everywhere and fiddle around with it, build what you like. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3rLu/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a :hover for each one of your .icons_cell classes. Or give all your .iconscell(NUMBER) a same class so you only need to write the css once.

```
.icons_cell1:hover {
    border: 3px solid grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very quick sample: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G3rLu/1/).

Just use `.class:hover{...}` to display a border when hovered. Do keep in mind that if no default border is set, the images will jump back and forth a little due to the addition of the border, so add a white border in the non-hover clause.

Comment: I don't want just a border, I want it to fill the space with grey. How would I do it so it doesn't jump

Comment: @user3075987 check for 'background-color' property in css

Answer (score 0):

Add some generic class that you want to attach to any element that you want the generic behavior.  For our purposes, let's call it `greyBoxOnHover`.

```
.greyBoxOnHover:hover {
  border: 3px solid grey;
}
```

Now just add that to any element that you want to have that behavior.  As in...

```
<div class="icons_cell4 greyBoxOnHover">
   ...
</div>
```